# Realm won't delete objects

Tags: realm

I'm working with RealmSwift 5.0.2 on iOS. I call `realm.delete(myObject)` inside a write transaction and the object is not removed from the realm. I confirmed this by directly inspecting my realm with Realm Studio.

Here's my delete method:

```
backgroundQueue.async {
    autoreleasepool {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        realm.beginWrite()
        if let person = realm.object(ofType: Person.self, forPrimaryKey: personId) {
            realm.delete(person)
        }
        try! realm.commitWrite()
    }
}
```

Edit: Further clarification of how Person object is obtained. **Note that I've confirmed that a valid Person object is found.**

Update: The problem turned out to be in other parts of the app, where the objects were getting re-added.

Comment: The question is a bit vague as we don't know what objects or data your functions return. like this for example `if let stored = findStored()` if stored is an object from an array, it may be valid but it won't be found or deleted. Please clarify and update the question with more details and review the following guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @Jay, I've edited the question.

Comment: The question is still not answerable because we don't know if the `findPerson` functions works because if it doesn't, the code will silently fail. We also don't know what it's returning if it does work ( a realm object? A string? Something else?). You also don't need the backgroundQueue and autorelease pool in this case. Clarifying the question with those important details, additional and more complete code, and doing some basic troubleshooting would help us to help you.

Comment: @Jay, ok .... how about now?

Comment: Excellent. When I copy and paste your *exact* code into a project, it deletes the person with `personId` correctly. Tried it 10 times with 10 different people. So you should do some further troubleshooting. For example, just before `realm.delete(person)` add a line `print(person)` and inspect the person object that prints to console to ensure it's there. You may also want to include your Person class in the question as there may be an issue with how that object is set up. Additionally, you could be accidentally using two different Realms so obviously a delete from one won't affect the other.

Comment: @Jay, thank you so much for taking the time and persisting with this. The problem turned out to be in other parts of the app, where objects were getting re-added.